# R - Identify potential duplicate records, then assign a single identifier

Tags: r

I have a table with several thousand "potential" duplicate people, and the task is to identify those potential duplicates and assign them all a common id.

I have used stringdist_inner_join on the columns I'm concerned with, to join the table onto itself and return all rows and their possible matches. This works well, in most cases, but I can get long chains of matches that ultimately should be identified as the same person, and this is where I'm stuck.

My sample source table might look like this:

```
 systemid    last_name
 --------    ---------
 13          Samison
 14          Samsun          
 15          Sanison
```

I use stringdist_inner_join on last_name to get a table that looks like this:

```
systemid.x    systemid.y
----------    ----------
13            15
14            13
15            13
```

but what I need to know is that all three of those records are potentially the same, so ultimately I want something like this:

```
finalid    systemid.x    systemid.y
-------    ----------    ----------
13         13            15
13         14            13
13         15            13
```

To make this more complicated, the number of these potential duplicates can be any number, and the relationship chain between them can be any length.  I might have id 13 match to 14, 14 match to 15, 15 match 21, and so one.

It's also possible I'm going about this all wrong and need to learn something else like compare.dedup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way to do this, but here is what I've done:

Sample table:

```
tbl1 <- tibble(userId = c(13, 14, 15, 16, 21)
               , lastName = c("Samison", "Samsun", "Sanison", "Simison", "Sumison"))
```

Map record pairs using compare.dedup:

```
mapped.tbl1 <- compare.dedup(tbl1, exclude = "userId"
                               , strcmp = TRUE, strcmpfun = levenshteinSim) %>% 
    epiWeights() %>%
    epiClassify(0.7) %>%
    getPairs(show = "links", single.rows = TRUE)
```

Group by my lastName column and eliminate duplicates

```
  mapped.tbl1 <- mapped.tbl1 %>% 
    group_by(lastName.2) %>% 
    mutate(rnk=order(order(desc(Weight)))) %>% 
    filter(rnk == 1)
```

Join my original table to my mapped table and update the userId with mutate:

```
  tbl1 <- tbl1 %>% 
    left_join(mapped.tbl1, by = c("userId" = "userId.2")) %>% 
    mutate(
      userId.2 = userId
      , userId = if_else(is.na(userId.1) == FALSE, userId.1, userId)
    ) %>% 
    select(names(tbl1))
```